# How to select few values with and condition?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have table example http://prntscr.com/msqpep
I need empty result when i am doing

```
SELECT * FROM prods 
WHERE prod_id = 3 and (fet_id = 1 and fet_id = 5)
```

but that code so not work `(fet_id = 1 and fet_id = 5)`  or `(fet_id = 1 and fet_id = 3)` 
    `"Where in"` is a best way but i need `WHERE IN(1 and 2 and 3)

By default `"WHERE IN"` working as `(1 or 2 or 3)`

When I select fet_id=1 and fet_id=3 i need two results
When i select fet_id=1 and fet_id=5 i need no result

Comment: fet_id = 1 and fet_id = 5) cannot work because it's impossible for this condition to ever be true.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
SELECT prod_id FROM prods GROUP by prod_id
HAVING (SUM(fet_id=1)>0
AND SUM(fet_id=5)>0)
OR 
(SUM(fet_id=1)>0
AND SUM(fet_id=3)>0)
```

HAVING filters groups WHERE filters rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT p1.id AS id1, p2.id AS id2
FROM `prods` p1 LEFT JOIN `prods` p2 ON p1.`prod_id` =  p2.`prod_id`
WHERE p1.`fet_id` = '1' AND p2.`fet_id` = '3'
```

**Output**

```
  id1   id2
  1      3
```

With input fet_id=1 & fet_id=5

```
SELECT p1.id AS id1, p2.id AS id2
FROM `prods` p1 LEFT JOIN `prods` p2 ON p1.`prod_id` =  p2.`prod_id`
WHERE p1.`fet_id` = '1' AND p2.`fet_id` = '5'
```

**Output**: No result

Comment: Yes, it is that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

And another one if need more then two values

```
SELECT res.* FROM (SELECT 3 as total,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `prods` as t1 WHERE t1.`fet_id` = 1 OR  t1.`fet_id` = 2 OR t1.`fet_id` = 5) as current,
t2.*
FROM `prods` as t2 WHERE t2.`fet_id` in (1,2,5)) as res WHERE res.total = res.current
```